# Android - Is there a way to trigger onKeyListener for the soft keyboard?

Tags: android

The developer reference mentions that OnKeyListener only works for hardware key events:

"Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener."

But I was wondering if there's a way to trigger it with the soft keyboard? I know it does trigger for some devices but it's not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 9/12/2013**
Looks like my old answer only worked on some soft keyboards but not others.
I tried looking around for an alternative and couldn't find anything that works consistently. In the end, I made a custom keyboard. Luckily, I just needed numbers for my keyboard so it was easy to create. I followed this guide on how to create a custom keyboard.
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

**Old Answer**
I searched around and it looks like there's no way to listen for keys with onKeyListener for the soft keyboard. However, I was able to just extend EditText and override onKeyUp() which works fine.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText
{
    public CustomEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        // Intercept keys here
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```